# Vim to accept commands like `vi path:line:column`

Tags: vim, vi

It's often that I get paths in the format `<path>:<line>:<column>` (from text matches such as `grep` or errors on code).

When I double click, it matches the whole string, including line and column, then I usually remove the column, and replace `:line` with `+line` to match `vi` parameter.

Therefore, I'd like having a hack to rapidly open vim at the right point just with a paste. Is there any config on vim level or alias I could use?!

Thanks

Comment: Works for me both from OS command line (`vim <path>:<line>:<column>`) and inside vim (`:edit <path>:<line>:<column>`).

Comment: Given that `foo.txt:5:10` is a valid file name, I'm not sure you would *want* Vim deciding whether the string should be parsed as "open foo.txt and move the cursor to line 5, column 10", or treated literally.

Comment: Just did an experiment: created `foo.txt` and `foo.txt:5:10`. Ran `vim foo.txt:5:10` — vim opened `foo.txt:5:10` at the first line, 1st column. I removed `foo.txt:5:10` and ran `vim foo.txt:5:10` — vim opened `foo.txt` at line 5, column 10. Quite a reasonable behaviour IMO.

Comment: It came to me now: I use [`vim-fetch`](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5089) plugin for so long I completely forgot about it.

Comment: I'm using [bogado/file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line)

Comment: In principle, you can trap `BufNewFile` , parse `<afile>` to see if it matches `path:line:column` pattern and then process it yourself. But this is precisely what all these plugins already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that trap the `BufNewFile,BufRead` events, parse out the file name and number(s), and redirect to the corresponding file:

- [file-file](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) is the minimalistic original plugin
- [vim-fetch](https://github.com/wsdjeg/vim-fetch) supports multiple ways of specifying the number(s), overloads some mappings (like `gf`), and even offers a `:Fetch` command

Answer (score 2):

[Use the quickfix list instead](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21054/how-to-load-files-as-a-quickfix-window-at-start-up):

> Vim has a startup option `-q` to read a quickfix file. So we have
>   options (depending on your shell): `cmd > results ; vim -q results`
>
> Or my favorite: `vim -q <(cmd)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's hugely useful. It does interest me, and fit my need, still, I'll accept the other answer which accurately answer my question